# Multidimensional array adding controls

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

How can i make the below code more efficient, with less lines.

Im adding some PictureBox elements to a two dimensinal array.

```
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i + " a = " + a);
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i + " b = " + b);
            pictureBoxArr[a, b] = new PictureBox();
            b++;
        }

        int aa = 1;
        int bb = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i + " aa = " + aa);
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i + " bb = " + bb);
            pictureBoxArr[aa, bb] = new PictureBox();
            bb++;
        }

        int aaa = 2;
        int bbb = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i + " aaa = " + aaa);
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i + " bbb = " + bbb);
            pictureBoxArr[aaa, bbb] = new PictureBox();
            bbb++;
        }
```

I was thinking something like this - but im kinda stuck.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; i++)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Language? Looks like `c#`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            pictureBoxArr[i, j] = new PictureBox();
        }
    }
```

You almost had it.

If you want something more re-usable, you could set up a couple variables to hold your bounds.

```
    int boundX = 10;
    int boundY = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < boundX ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < boundY ; j++)
        {
            pictureBoxArr[i, j] = new PictureBox();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i + " a = " + i);
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + j + " b = " + j);
        pictureBoxArr[i, j] = new PictureBox();
   }
}
```

Dude, you are very close